# Flink-like barrier for Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Is there an equivalent of a [Flink barrier](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/internals/stream_checkpointing.html#barriers) for Tensorflow?

There seems to not be a way to interact with the executor from any given kernel except by throwing an exception, and any deviation from a "pure" dataflow execution is not allowed, such as

- Producing no output for a given input
- Producing multiple outputs for a given input (e.g. splitting a sentence into words). I get around this by having such a kernel take a queue reference and do the enqueuing itself, but this feels like a modularity violation.
- Receiving some sort of "control tuple / Tensor" so that multiple kernels can synchronize at some point (e.g. to implement a barrier). In other words, the only schedulable code for each kernel is `Compute()` on the normal `Input` and `Output` Tensors.

*Is there any way to get Tensorflow to be able to behave more like a streaming framework?* Is using Tensorflow as a streaming framework an unintended / improper use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While TensorFlow kernels can't behave like proper units in a streaming framework, as they are, as you pointed out, called once per set of inputs and expected to produce one set of outputs each time they're called, there are alternatives.

The [`tf.contrib.data`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/data) framework is built on the concept of a `Dataset`, which is a unit which has all the properties you specified above (maybe not the control tuple yet, but it'd be easy to add).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using tge recently released Flink ML "integration" with Tensorflow?

https://github.com/FlinkML/flink-tensorflow